# How did Ariko corner Toni Anji to a place where avalanches happen easily?

Tags: golden-kamuy

In the 3rd episode of Golden Kamuy 4, Ariko made noises by breaking branches and the like to lead Toni to a place where avalanches happen easily so that he can trigger one to bury Toni.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

But I don't get it. Ariko is chasing Toni from behind. So, if Ariko made some noises, then the noise could only come from behind of Toni. Toni could just keep going straight without changing direction. Actually, if you keep going straight, your enemy would need more time to chase up with you. I don't get it why noises from behind could corner Toni to a place that is planned by Ariko.